# Apk file Generation -Issue

Tags: android, apk

I have created a signed .apk file and I've followed all of the steps (Created Keystore,Password and validity yrs,etc...) and I have an .apk file.

When I install this to any mobile device, it shows the installation failed, so I checked the apk file.

It contains only

1. META-INF Folder
2. classes.dex.

I'm unable to find the other files. This is the first time I'm facing this issue.

Does anyone know what may cause this?

Comment: Jeez, kinda rude to start your question with 'geeks, '

Answer (score 2):

Installing a production release over a debug release and vice versa will cause a failed installation.

Uninstall the current version first.

Keystore signed versions can be installed on top of each other.
Debug signed versions can be installed on top of each other.
Debug and Keystore versions cannot be installed on top of each other.

Comment: I tried to create a simple hello world and created keystore,developed apk ,but still im facing the same issue.

Comment: the Thing is that .apk does not contain res folder for the very first time for a fresh project.

Comment: Are you using Ant, Maven, or an IDE to build the bad apks?

Comment: If 'Project->Build Automatically' is checked, you shouldn't have to clean the build each time in order to get a res folder. Helios is 2 (almost 3) versions behind. Try using Eclipse Juno SR2.

Comment: i solved the issue.....some privilege issue...if do the same thing as a super user in the same system everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the issue.....some privilege issue...if i do the same thing as a super user in the same system everything works fine(Generated APK).

Thanks friends